# How do I get an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I am mocking up several classes in order to create unit tests in a Symfony 2.7 application. One of my tests includes the following code:

```
    $this->entityManagerMock
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->willReturn(
            new EntityRepository($this->entityManagerMock, DistributedVideo::class)
        );
```

... and when I run my tests, I get the following complaint:

> Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata, string given,
>   called in
>   /usr/src/app/src/MyCompany/AppBundle/Tests/Distribution/DistributionServiceTest.php
>   on line 139 and defined

How do I get an instance of the metadata object that Doctrine seems to want?

(For now I will try to mock that item using `createMock`, but I'm interested in other answers as well.)

Comment: A mock entity manager shouldn't ever be returning a real repository. Ideally your target class would deal directly with the EntityRepository class instead of calling it via getRepository, and you could just inject mocks of both dependencies from your test, but a mock returning a mock is a viable solution.